# How to call functions defined in types_c.h in opencv3

Tags: opencv

I am working on a project with opencv3.4. The project was originally written with opencv2.4. There are some functions that cannot be called by typing `cv::function_name`, and it is noted these functions are defined in the `types_c.h` header files (of specific modules).

For example, there is a function `cvmSet()` used in my project, if I write `cv::cvmSet`, `error C2039: 'cvmSet': is not a member of 'cv'`.  This function is defined in `opencv2/core/types_c.h`.

I wonder how many ways available to call this kind of old fashioned functions?

Comment: **Don't**. Update your code to use C++ functions. And you can switch directly to OpenCV 4.0. The obsolete C api has been deprecated for years, and now finally removed

Comment: @Miki OpenCV4.0 has no c support?

Comment: No...............

Comment: @Miki does the latest version have all the equivalent functions for the old fashioned?

Comment: Mostly, just a few algorithms have been removed.